# AngularJS: Data could not be saved

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I am trying to save an updated function using angularJS. Till now i can edit the data, the data are can be updated on the database side, but its not showing in the frontend side. Unless i have to logout and login once again to view the updated result. Can i know how to fix this bug.

This is my controller.js code:

```
.controller('FilmDetailController', //havent done yet
            [
                '$scope', 
                'dataService', 
                '$routeParams',
                '$location',
                '$window',
                'UserInfo',

                function ($scope, dataService, $routeParams, $location,$window, UserInfo){
                    //var userName=dataService.getSessionService('user');
                    if(UserInfo.loggedIn){
                        $scope.film = [ ];
                        $scope.filmCount = 0;

                        var getFilmDetail = function (moviecode) {
                            dataService.getFilmDetail(moviecode).then(
                                function (response) {
                                    $scope.film = response.data.ResultSet.Result;
                                    //$scope.userLoginEmail = dataService.getSessionService('userEmail');
                                    $scope.showSuccessMessage = true;
                                    $scope.successMessage = "Film Success";
                                },
                                function (err){
                                    $scope.status = 'Unable to load data ' + err;
                                }
                            );  // end of getStudents().then
                        };

                        $scope.editedFilm = {};
                        $scope.save_note = function ($event,film) {
                            $scope.editedFilm = film;
                            dataService.saveNote($scope).then(
                                function (response) {
                                    // getFilmDetail();
                                    $window.location.href = '#/movieList';
                                    //$window.location.reload();
                                    console.log("done");
                                },

                                function (err){
                                    $scope.status = 'Unable to load data ' + err;
                                }
                            );
                            // $scope.reloadRoute = function () {
                            //     $location.path('/movieList');
                            //     $window.location.reload()
                            // }//end of reload route fnction

                        }

                        // only if there has been a courseid passed in do we bother trying to get the students
                        if ($routeParams && $routeParams.filmid) {
                        // console.log($routeParams.filmid);
                            getFilmDetail($routeParams.filmid);
                        }
                    }else{
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }

                }
            ]
        );
```

Once i click on the save note button the note should be updated in both angular side and also the database side. Currently it can only be updated in the database side except the angular side. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are u using $scope.film  to display the data on front end.

Comment: yes i am using the $scope.film to display my data

Comment: then u should either called getFilmDeails() after updating response ie after console.log("done") or assign $scope.editedFilm to $scope.Film

Comment: i am hoping after refreshing updated data is displaying. Is it so?

Comment: yes after i login and logout i can view the data being updated

Comment: try with calling getFilmDetail()

Comment: i tried its showing error message Result undefined

Comment: hav u passed the parameter while calling function? Like getFilmDetail($routeParams.filmid);

Comment: so how can it get the data ? bcoz in ur function defination u passed paramtere on the basis of which it gets the details of dat particular film. Try it by passing the approriate parameter value while calling function

Comment: after passing the parameter also the same it seems

Comment: u r using $scope.film = response.data.ResultSet.Result before this print the reponse . Also check whether request is going..

Comment: i tried to console log it, i am getting `Object {data: Object}` this in the response

Comment: u just leave dis.. and put $scope.film = film is place of function

Comment: That didnt worked too.

Comment: I don't know how your dataService is implemented, but probably you'r not in the AngularJs digest cycle anymore in the then of the Promise. You can fix by $scope.apply() or (better) use $q. (dataService.saveNote($scope).then(function () {//digest cycle gone});

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell it looks like you need to store your note data in a service, and when the note has been successfully saved in your database, you need to push the new note into your service data.

I created a simple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robrothedev/vgbqyv10/

```
function ItemService() {
  var service = {
    items: [],
    addItem: addItem
 };

 return service;

function addItem(new_item) {
   // run your http request and if the response is valid,
   // push the new item to your service array
   // $http.post(url,new_item).then(function(response) {
   //      service.items.push(response.data.new_item);
   // });
 }
```

}

```
function ItemsCtrl(ItemService) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.items = ItemService.items;
  vm.new_item = {};
  vm.addItem = addItem;

  function addItem() {
    ItemService.addItem(vm.new_item);
    vm.new_item = {};
  }
}
```